# How to skip a callback after triggered[rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I have a callback like this:
`after_commit :sponsored_notification, on: [:create, :update]`

```
def sponsored_notification
      current_time = Time.now.in_time_zone(self.try(:timezone)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      if current_time < self.try(:notify_time) && self.try(:is_sent) == false
        run_time = self.updated_at + (self.try(:notify_time) - current_time.to_time).seconds
        SponsoredNotificationWorker.perform_at(run_time, self.id)
      end
    end
```

My problem is when I create a sponsored then update it, I received two notification, but I just want to receive one, the newest sponsored info should be sent. I supposed that in this case callback was triggered two times. How can I skip the action for creating if update happen?

Comment: Can you please add you code for more detail

Comment: @Usar edited, the logic is quite complicated for one who first time reading it, but my goal is just to handle the callback

Comment: Why don't you first check sponsored present before by using find_or_create_by before creating notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to re-think how your process looks like, and then refactor the code to add pieces to achieve what you describe.

The callback you added will just fire every time you `:create` or `:update` the model, that is, twice if you create it and update it. If you enqueue a worker on each call, then you'll have that executed at the `run_time` you pass to `perform_at`.

Depending on your end goal here, you can do plenty of things. Do you want to notify once, ever, regardless of the subsequent updates? Or you just don't want to swarm the user with notifications?

In the first case, I'd move the logic to the worker:

- Keep the callback like this (well, refactor it to simplify code)
- Add a `notified` boolean flag to the model you set to `true` at the momento you enqueue the job, ie at the last step of the callback.
- In the worker, retrieve the object and if it was `notified` before, then just skip and don't do nothing.
- Then you can change the `perform_at` with a plain `perform_async`.

In the second case, you may want to go with something like "notify first thing and then wait for 1 hour no notify anything else".

- Change that boolean for a datetime `notified_at` attribute and store it to `Time.current` in the callback.
- Define a time window to group notifications, in a constant for example in the model `NOTIFICATION_WINDOW = 1`, in hours for instance.
- In the worker, change your logic to check `your_object#notified_at` against `YourObject#NOTIFICATION_WINDOW.hours.ago` to see if you need to notify or discard.
- Change your `perform_at` to `perform_async` as well, so notify now and remain silent for an hour.
- Have in mind that this approach will notify the first thing (`:create`) and don't do anything about the next any number of `:update`s for one hour.

If you want something smarter, like "grouping a bunch of notifications" and send them all together, then you need a different approach. For instance, writing `Notification` entries in your DB that have some `notified` boolean flag, and then scheduling a `rake` task to take all `unnotified` `Notification`s from the DB and dispatching them, in group, however you like. That will mean dropping the worker from your current callback and creating a different Worker that will be scheduled on a regular based (each 5min? each hour?).

These are some some ideas that may fit with your requirement. Clarify it first, try somethings and maybe we can narrow down a bit more.